# why does pymongo's find_one fail silently? (nginx/uwsgi/flask/gevent/pymongo)

Tags: nginx, flask, pymongo, uwsgi, gevent

**Summary:** Pymongo appears to fail silently for no reason in my flask+gevent+uwsgi+nginx app. I would love some pointers on where I should look

I'm a newcomer to web application programming (and to python), please bear with me. I'm porting an app from Heroku to an OpenStack provider, and am finding that code that worked fine on the former fails intermittently and silently on the latter. I wonder if anyone can shed some light on this.

This is the function in question:

`emergencies` is a pymongo Collection. This is correctly instantiated.

`user_id` is the User id I'm looking for. It's correct.

```
22 def get_emergency_by_user(user_id):
23     print "going to find emergency by user:"+user_id
24     print emergencies
25     print EmergencyDict.user_id
26     try:
27         emergency = emergencies.find_one({EmergencyDict.user_id: user_id})
28     except:
29         print 'mongo failed'
30     print 'this should appear'
31     print 'emergency - %s' % emergency
32     return emergency
```

Here is the output from the function (line numbers added for easy reference):

**Failure Case**

```
23 going to find emergency by user:UnitTestScript
24 Collection(Database(Connection('[redacted]', [redacted]), u'[redacted]'), u'emergencies')
25 userid
```

So I can see that line 23 through 25 work fine, and I assume that line 27 is called. But I get **nothing** below that. Neither line 29 (the `except:` case) nor line 30 ever run.

The strangest thing is that there are times during the day when this isn't a problem at all, and it works perfectly. In these cases, it looks more like this (line numbers added for easy reference):

**Success Case**

```
23 going to find emergency by user:UnitTestScript
24 Collection(Database(Connection('[redacted]', [redacted]), u'[redacted]'), u'emergencies')
25 userid
30 this should appear
31 {'_obj'...[a bunch of json representing the correct document]...'}
```

I haven't been able to isolate anything makes it work though. It's maddening, and I don't know where to look next.

**some things I have tried**

I have read some articles that suggest that I need to have the `from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()` line in my imports; I have done this.

I have also read that you can't use uwsgi+gevent with multiple threads, so my uwsgi is configured with 1 thread.

**tl;dr**
Pymongo appears to fail silently for no reason in my flask+gevent+uwsgi+nginx app. I would love some pointers on where I should look

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I am having problems with uwsgi + pymongo where pymongo raise *Connection refused [errno 111]* when run from uwsgi.

Comment: We ended up moving away from uwsgi and back to Heroku I'm afraid. I don't remember exactly what was going on... but if memory serves, the problem was with something in my requirements.txt file. I was using an old version of... pymongo, I think. I totally forgot about this question! I'll try and work out what happened there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remembered how we solved this. The version of pymongo in the requirements.txt was old. I updated it to the newest version, and it was fine after that.